# delete numbers in a column csv

Tags: bash, csv

I have a data.csv with a column with values like:

```
2014/07/08  21:30 UTC
```

and I want to delete the hour UTC and get only YYYYMMDD

```
20140708
```

The time, hour and minutes can change, so, I can have 21:30, 22:00, 22:30 and so on...

Now I use the following code, but I would like to delete the hour and time using regular expressions...anybody knows, I tried with [0-9]*h UTC but it doesn't run..

```
awk -F "," '{gsub("/","",$1);gsub("22:30h UTC","",$1);gsub("22:00h UTC","",$1); print $1 ","  $2","  $4","  $3}' data.csv
```

Comment: `awk '{gsub("/","");print $1}' file` ?

Answer (score 0):

`date` to the rescue:

```
$ date -d"2014/07/08  21:30 UTC" "+%Y%m%d"
20140708
```

Please provide full text sample to indicate how to update everything.

For example this is an approach:

```
$ cat a
1,2014/07/08  21:30 UTC,3
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {cmd="date -d \""$2"\" \"+%Y%m%d\""; cmd | getline var; $2=var; print}' a
1,20140708,3
```

Comment: Another way for your second example `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{gsub("/","",$2);$2=substr($2,0,8)}1'`

Comment: Well thanks, but that is already covered by Avinash's answer and your comment on the question. Also, I prefer using `date` so that it handles the date itself, not as a regex. This way new formats will be easier to get.

Comment: It's not quite the same as Avinash's as his is assuming there are no other fields, but okay :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this simple awk command,

```
$ echo '2014/07/08  21:30 UTC' | awk '{gsub(/\//,"",$1); print $1}'
20140708
```

Another one,

```
$ echo '2014/07/08  21:30 UTC' | awk '{gsub(/ .*$/,""); gsub("/",""); print}'
20140708
```

The first gsub function remove all the characters from the first space upto the last. And the second gsub function removes only the `/` symbol from the remaining part.

Comment: could use this as it isn't a regular expression and is only on $1 anyway `awk '{gsub("/","");print $1}'`

Comment: we have to be accurate.:-)

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to delete the hour and time using regular expressions...

Assuming the use of `awk` is not mandatory, you might prefer using `sed`. Given that input set:

```
sh$ cat inputfile
DATE TIME, VAL1, VAL2
2014/07/08  21:30 UTC, xxxxxx, x1
2014/07/08  22:30 UTC, yyyyyy, y2
2014/07/08  23:30 UTC, zzzzzz, z3
2014/07/08  23:45 UTC, aaaaaa, a4
2014/07/08  23:55 UTC, bbbbbb, b5
```

The following substitution will do the trick (this will *not* alter header lines that might be present in your data file):

```
sh$ sed -r 's|^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2}).*UTC|\1\2\3|' < inputfile 
DATE TIME, VAL1, VAL2
20140708, xxxxxx, x1
20140708, yyyyyy, y2
20140708, zzzzzz, z3
20140708, aaaaaa, a4
20140708, bbbbbb, b5
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it runs! exactly what does UTC|\1\2\3|?